# What does good condition mean in a Pokemon Contest?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

In Pokemon Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald, the description for Rock Smash on the Contest Moves page says "The appeal works well if the user's condition is good". What does this mean? How can I tell if my condition is good in a Pokemon Contest?

[image: Description for rock smash]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good condition is marked as a blue star during the contest. It's gained through some moves that are described as *"Ups the user's condition"*. You can gain up to three stars in a single contest, and for each star you have, you get an extra appeal point on your next move.

These moves are:

- Cool

  - Cosmic Power, Dragon Dance, Howl
- Beauty

  - Bulk Up, Growth, Meditate, Silver Wind, Swords Dance, Tail Glow
- Cute

  - Amnesia, Belly Drum, Refresh, Sharpen
- Tough

  - Acid Armor, Ancientpower, Swallow